# java 8 java.util.function.Consumer break

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8

for loop and foreach can use break instruction. but Java8 Consumer.

```
beans.forEach(v->{
    if (v.id != 100){
        //break or continue
    }
    v.doSomeThing();
});
```

Comment: There is no simple way to do it - you could filter the elements or limit the number of elements but you can't easily break the forEach on a random condition.

Comment: You are using the wrong tools for the wrong job here, if you need such a condition, then just go with the regular for-loop, especially when you are not working with streams.

Comment: @Holame A `continue` within a `forEach` is basically just filtering on the negation, so you could do something like `beans.stream().filter(v -> v.id == 100).forEach(v -> v.doSomeThing())`.

Comment: @StuartMarks indeed - you can close the question as a duplicate of that other question and both links will appear in the close reason.

Answer (score 1):

It would have been nice to get away from helper methods in Java 8, but if you really need to break in a loop (filtering or setting a limit as @assylias suggests, is the way to avoid this) then just write a helper method:

```
public static <T> void forEach(Iterable<T> iterable, Function<T, Boolean> f)
{
  for (T item : iterable)
  {
    if (!f.apply(item))
    {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

This helper method can then be used like this:

```
List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);

forEach(
  integers,
  (i) -> {
    System.out.println(i);
    return i < 2;
  }
);
```

Which prints:

```
1
2
```

Answer (score 0):

With Streams each element should be viewed independently or with as little knowledge as possible of the other items in the Stream; this is in part because of the possibility of using parallel Streams. A quote from the Stream JavaDoc:

> Stream pipelines may execute either sequentially or in parallel.  This
>   execution mode is a property of the stream.  Streams are created
>   with an initial choice of sequential or parallel execution.  (For example,
>   *Collection#stream()* creates a sequential stream,
>   and *Collection#parallelStream()* creates
>   a parallel one.)  This choice of execution mode may be modified by the
>   *Stream#sequential()* or *Stream#parallel()* methods, and may be queried with
>   the *Stream#isParallel()* method.

So, using `break` in a parallel Stream could have unforeseen consequences.

The best idea is probably using a traditional `for`-loop if you want to be able to `break` or to filter the stream so as to not require a `break`. Or maybe you have to rethink your logic entirely as Streams offer quite a few new possibilities.